# Show that a Sophie Germain prime $p$ is of the form $6k - 1$ for $p > 3$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

A Sophie Germain prime is a prime $p$ such that $2p + 1$ is also prime.

According to a comment in OEIS A023212 (https://oeis.org/A023212), such a prime $p$ is of the form $6k - 1$ for $p > 3$.

How would one show that?

Comment: Hint:  mod ($6$) every prime greater than $3$ must be of the form $6k+1$ or $6k-1$.  can you show that the first case is impossible here?

Comment: @lulu  Good hint.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every prime larger than $3$ must be of the form $6k\pm 1$.

(why? Hint: $6k$ and $6k\pm 2$ are even and $6k+3$ is divisible by $3$).

For contradiction, let a Sophie Germain prime $p>3$ be of the form $6k+1$.

But then $2p+1=2(6k+1)+1=3(4k+1)$,

so $2p+1$ is divisible by $3$, so $2p+1=3$, so $p=1$, contradiction.