# When is 2 a primitive root for a Sophie Germain prime $p$ or its associate $2p + 1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, primitive-roots

A prime $p$ is a Sophie Germain prime if its associate $2p + 1$ is also prime.

When is $2$ a primitive root for a Sophie Germain prime $p$ or its associate $2p + 1$?

A previous question found that a Sophie Germain prime $p > 3$ is of the form $6k - 1$: Frank Hubeny (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/312852/frank-hubeny), Show that a Sophie Germain prime $p$ is of the form $6k - 1$ for $p > 3$, URL (version: 2016-02-21): [Show that a Sophie Germain prime $p$ is of the form $6k - 1$ for $p > 3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1665580)

So far from the discussion there is an answer for the associate prime $2p + 1$.  If $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$ then $2p + 1 \equiv 3 \pmod{8}$.  This implies $2$ is a primitive root modulo $2p + 1$ since that would make $2$ a quadratic nonresidue of $2p + 1$.

Can anything be said about the Sophie Germain prime $p$ itself given that $2p + 1$ is a prime?

Comment: Did you unintentionally omit the word "not" in the first sentence of the third paragraph?  After all the Question you linked at the end of that paragraph proves as much.  Is there any reason to think determining which Sophie Germain primes have $2$ as a primitive root is easier than the general case? Cf. [Artin's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots) and the related [OEIS sequence A001122](https://oeis.org/A001122) for notes and empirical data.

Comment: http://number.subwiki.org/wiki/Safe_prime_has_plus_or_minus_two_as_a_primitive_root

Comment: $2$ is a primitive root mod $2p+1$ if and only if $2^p\not\equiv 1\pmod{2p+1}$. By [Euler's Criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) we get $2^p\equiv \left(\frac{2}{2p+1}\right)\pmod{2p+1}$. If $p=2$, then $2$ is a primitive root mod $2p+1$. If $p\neq 2$, then clearly $2p+1\not\equiv \{1,5\}\pmod{8}$. If $2p+1\equiv 3\pmod{8}$, then by [Quadratic Reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#.C2.B12_and_the_second_supplement) $2$ is a primitive root mod $2p+1$. If $2p+1\equiv 7\pmod{8}$, then $2$ is not a primitive root mod $2p+1$.

Comment: So it's clear when $2$ is a primitive root mod $2p+1$. I'm not sure about mod $p$.

Comment: No, $2p+1\not\equiv\{3,5\}\pmod 8$, @user236182

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $2p+1\equiv 3\pmod{8}$ is equivalent to $p\equiv 1\pmod{4}$, which is possible. Whereas $2p+1\equiv 1\pmod{8}$ is equivalent to $p\equiv 0\pmod{4}$, which is impossible.

Comment: You wrote "Clearly, $2p+1\not\equiv{1,5}\pmod 8$." That is not true. $2$ is a square modulo $2p+1$ when $2p+1\equiv 1\pmod{8}$ and is not a square if $2p+1\equiv 5\pmod 8$. So it is unclear what you are asserting there. @user236182

Comment: @ThomasAndrews $p$ is an odd prime, so $2p+1\not\equiv \{1,5\}\pmod{8}$.

Comment: When $p\equiv 3\pmod 4$, then $2p+1\equiv 7\pmod 8$.  @user236182

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I was only claiming that if $p$ is an odd prime, then $2p+1\not\equiv \{1,5\}\pmod{8}$. Proof: If $2p+1\equiv 1\pmod{8}$, then $p\equiv 0\pmod{4}$, impossible. If $2p+1\equiv 5\pmod{8}$, then $p\equiv 2\pmod{4}$, so $p$ is even, impossible.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I wasn't thinking about Quadratic Reciprocity there. Only using basic divisibility properties. If $p$ is an odd prime, then $2p+1\equiv \{3,7\}\pmod{8}$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews You misunderstood me and thought I was referring to when $2$ is a square mod $2p+1$. This is when $2p+1\in\{1,7\}\pmod{8}$. What I was claiming was that if $p$ is an odd prime, then $2p+1\equiv \{3,7\}\pmod{8}$.

Comment: I misunderstood, true, but I think you bear some blame. In comments, in particular, arguments should be linear. Since you had just made an argument involving Legendre, it is normal to assume you are still talking about that argument. @user236182

Comment: @hardmath  I fixed the typo.  Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I didn't mention Quadratic Reciprocity until when it had to be used.

Comment: You included a Legendre symbol in your very previous step.  @user236182

Comment: Thank you for the discussion.  To summarize, if the Sophie Germain prime $p$ is such that $p \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, then $2p + 1 \equiv 3 \pmod{8}$ and $2$ is a primitive root modulo $2p+1$.  Can one say anything about $2$ being a primitive root modulo $p$ except to note when $2$ would be a quadratic nonresidue?